# Coeffaceable - universal $\delta$ functor

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ be two abelian categories. A functor $F:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is coeffaceable if for every $A$ there is a surjection $u:P \to A$ such that $F(u) = 0$. If $F_*$ is a homological $\delta$-functor such that each $F_n$ is coeffaceable (except $F_0$), then $F_*$ is universal.

The proof goes by induction. Suppose that $T_*$ is a homological $\delta$-functor and that $\phi_0 : T_0 \to F_0$ is given. We want to show that there is a unique extension of $\phi_0$ to a morphism of $\delta$-functors $\phi:T_* \to F_*$. Suppose inductively that $\phi_i : T_i \to F_i$ are defined for $0 \leq i < n$. Given $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$, select a surjection $u: P \to A$ such that $F_n(u) = 0$. We have a short exact sequence $0 \to K \to P \to A \to 0$ and a commutative diagram

\begin{array}
\mbox{} & T_n(A) \stackrel{\delta_n}{\longrightarrow} & T_{n-1}(K) \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & T_{n-1}(P) \\
& & \downarrow{\phi_{n-1}(K)} & \downarrow{\phi_{n-1}(P)} \\
F_n(P) \stackrel{F_n(u)=0}{\longrightarrow} & F_n(A)  \stackrel{\delta_n}{\longrightarrow}& F_{n-1}(A) \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & F_{n-1}(P)  
\end{array}

As $F_n(u)=0$, $\delta_n$ on the second row is injective. This implies that there exists a map $\phi_n(A):T_n(A) \to F_n(A)$.

The question I have is to show that $\phi_n(A)$ is defined independent of choice of $u : P \to A$. The idea suggested in Weibel's book (Exercise 2.4.5) goes as follow:

If there is another $u' : P' \to A$ such that $F_n(u') = 0$, there we have

\begin{array}
\mbox{} 0 \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & K' \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & P' \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & A \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & 0\\
& & & \downarrow{\mathrm{id}} &\\
\mbox{} 0 \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & K \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & P \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & A \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & 0\\
\end{array}

What I would like to see is a morphism from $P'$ to $P$, this is true if we assume $P'$ is projective (in the case when $F_n$ are left derived functors and assuming $\mathcal{A}$ has enough projectives). I have had a hard time figuring out why there should be a morphism. If there is not a morphism from $P'$ to $P$, how to proceed to show that $\phi_n(A)$ is well-defined (independent of choice of $u:P \to A$)?

Comment: There is a map $P'\to A$ and a surjection $P\to A$, so you can lift this using that $P'$ is projective to get $P'\to P$ making the square commute. Once this is done, there is a unique map $K'\to K$ making the whole diagram commute.

Comment: But here we have not assumed P' is projective. We have just one surjection, this could be any. I know the argument when we assume P' is projective but having difficulty for general object P.